# how to set the number of nodes in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, nodes

I'm using a hadoop cluster administered by our department technicians. To use that I only need to set parameters in two files (core-site.xml and mapred-site.xml) and I'm good to go.

My question is, is there a way to control the number of nodes involved in my hadoop program? I understand if I'm administering the cluster myself I could modify the number of duplicates in the configuration file. But since I do not have access to that file, I seem to be out of luck.

I'm aware of setNumMapTasks() and setNumReduceTasks() methods. These two methods could set the number of map/reduce tasks programmatically. But those numbers do not necessarily translate to the actual running nodes right?

I heard Amazon EC2 allows you to set the number of nodes involved by using a command, does regular hadoop implementation allow that?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this link :http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module7.html

Answer (score 0):

Nope. It cant be done via program. You can change the configuration to make it happen